# Function generates different random number each time

Tags: python

By using Python, How can I make x,y, and z values different by having a different random number q between (0,1) each time when I use q through the whole code?
#####################################################

```
import random



def get_rand_number(min_value, max_value):
    """
    This functions gets a random number from a uniform distribution between
    the two input values [min_value, max_value] inclusively
    Args:
    - min_value (float)
    - max_value (float)
    Return:
    - Random number between this range (float)
    """
    range = max_value - min_value
    choice = random.uniform(0,1)
    return min_value + range*choice

q = get_rand_number(0,1)


x = 2 * q
y = 2 * q
z = 2 * q

print (x)
print (y)
print(z)
```

########################################

output:
0.0008081435950477722,
0.0008081435950477722,
0.0008081435950477722

Comment: `x = 2 * get_rand_number(0,1)`, `y = 2 * get_rand_number(0,1)`, guess the line for z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you mean is that q must have different values every time it is multiplied by 2 in the `x`, `y`, `z` values.

This is what I think the solution is.

```
import random

// The get_rand_number was unnecessary so I'm removing that.

x = 2 * random.uniform(0,1)
y = 2 * random.uniform(0,1)
z = 2 * random.uniform(0,1)

print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get one random value and save it in the `q` variable and then use the same value in all three dimensions (`x, y, z`):

```
q = get_rand_number(0,1)

x = 2 * q
y = 2 * q
z = 2 * q
```

If you want to have three different random number then call the random number generation for the three dimensions:

```
x = 2 * get_rand_number(0,1)
y = 2 * get_rand_number(0,1)
z = 2 * get_rand_number(0,1)
```